# Couchbase opening bucket just after create fail

Tags: python, python-3.x, couchbase

I'm creating some python scripts for automatic testing some Couchbase operations.

There is something unexpected while executing this code:

```
 for i in range(0, BUCKETS_AMOUNT): # BUCKETS_AMOUNT = 4
        bucket_name = '%s%s' % (BUCKET_NAME_PREFIX, i) # BUCKET_NAME_PREFIX = 'test_bck_'
        print('Creating bucket: %s' % bucket_name)
        admin.bucket_create(bucket_name, ram_quota=512, replicas=1)

        print('Opening bucket: %s' % bucket_name)
        bucket = cluster.open_bucket(bucket_name)
        print('Bucket: %s' % bucket)
        inserted_data[bucket_name] = _fill_bucket(bucket)
```

---

```
<Key='/pools/default/buckets/test_bck_1', RC=0x3B[HTTP Operation failed. Inspect status code for details], HTTP Request failed. Examine 'objextra' for full result, Results=1, C Source=(src/http.c,144), OBJ=HttpResult<rc=0x0, value=b'Requested resource not found.\r\n', http_status=404, url=/pools/default/buckets/test_bck_1, tracing_context=0, tracing_output=None>, Tracing Output={"/pools/default/buckets/test_bck_1": null}>
Creating bucket: test_bck_0
Opening bucket: test_bck_0
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_backup (__main__.TestBackup)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "couchbase_backup_test.py", line 29, in test_backup
    expected = create_and_fill_test_buckets(self.cluster, self.admin)
  File "/u01/app/couchbase/bucket_data_util.py", line 41, in create_and_fill_test_buckets
    bucket = cluster.open_bucket(bucket_name)
  File "/u01/app/couchbase/env_cb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/couchbase/cluster.py", line 144, in open_bucket
    rv = self.bucket_class(str(connstr), **kwargs)
  File "/u01/app/couchbase/env_cb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/couchbase/bucket.py", line 273, in __init__
    self._do_ctor_connect()
  File "/u01/app/couchbase/env_cb/lib/python3.6/site-packages/couchbase/bucket.py", line 282, in _do_ctor_connect
    self._connect()
couchbase.exceptions._ProtocolError_0x16 (generated, catch ProtocolError): <RC=0x16[Data received on socket was not in the expected format], There was a problem while trying to send/receive your request over the network. This may be a result of a bad network or a misconfigured client or server, C Source=(src/bucket.c,1066)>

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In this example bucket `test_bck_0` is created and filled, but it seems like trying to open `test_bck_1` before even creating it.
When I'm executing this code remotely - everything works perfectly. But I need to run this locally from actual node.
There is slight version difference, but I have no possibility to align that.

Couchbase server version: **5.1**

It works remotely from:

- OS: *Windows 7 x64*
- Python: *3.4.4*
- couchbase: *2.3.5*

Does not work from:

- OS: *Red Hat Enterprise 7.5*
- Python: *3.6.3*
- couchbase: *2.4.0*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, the problem is that creating a bucket is an asynchronous action so there needs to be a delay between issuing the create bucket request and opening the bucket.

Adding something like this between creating and opening the bucket will help:

```
import time
time.sleep(5);
```

You probably aren't seeing this happen when running your script against a remote cluster because it's likely a dedicated cluster with more resources (CPU / RAM), plus network latency will add a little.

Comment: Yes, I actually noticed that it's asynchronous. Is there any better way without using sleep? Can I make it work with some `onCallback()`?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`couchbase-cli bucket-create`](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/5.1/cli/cbcli/couchbase-cli-bucket-create.html) to create buckets and many more operations than SDK API exposes.